# Why does the following code gives an error?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to learn about inheritance and I came across this problem.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Parent
{
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println("show from parent");
    }
}
class Child extends Parent
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Parent p=new Child();
        p.show();
        p.display();
    }
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println("show from child");
    }
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("display from child");
    }
}
```

And the error is:

```
G:\javap>javac Child.java
Child.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
                p.display();
                 ^
  symbol:   method display()
  location: variable p of type Parent
1 error
```

If I'm able to access `show()` then why am I not able to access `display()` knowing that `display()` is inherited and is also present in the class definition of `Child class.`

Comment: `display()` is not present in the parent class...

Comment: See the base type of `p`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must understand the distinction between the *run time type* and the *compile time type*.

At run time your variable `p` holds a reference to a `Child` instance. So calling the `show` method will run the code in `Child#show` because this overrides the method `Parent#show`.

At compile time, the compiler can only know about the *declared type* of the variable. And this is `Parent`. So the compiler can only allow access to the fields and methods of type `Parent`, but not of type `Child`.

The `display` method simply isn't declared in `Parent`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

if u want to call the display method of client then you must need to create object of child class.
eg.
     Child child=new Child();

otherwise you need to write display method in parent class.

the rules is reference of parent class cant call member of child.

Answer (score 0):

Display() method not in parent class.that is the error .you are access parent class show method not child class.if you are trying to access method in parent class using object you dont need methods in child class